# AWS credentials in Active directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-directory-services

I have just started exploring AWS active directory. Our company does not have an LDAP/AD account. We use google apps for authentication. I am looking to use an application that does not support google apps but does LDAP. All our employees have AWS credentials to login to console.

Is there any way I can use these AWS credentials to set up a simple AD? Then I will be using this AD to authenticate inside the 3rd party application.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you clarify?  Do you want to know if your existing AWS user credentials can be stored in AD or do you want to know if you can create a Simple AD with your current AWS account?

Comment: sure. I want to know if our existing aws credentials (for all users) can be used to create simple AD. Thanks!!

Comment: @RodrigoM any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Controlling Access to AWS Directory Service Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/iam_policy.html):

> By default, IAM users don't have permission to AWS Directory Service
>   resources. To allow IAM users to manage AWS Directory Service
>   resources, you must create an IAM policy that explicitly grants IAM
>   users permission to create and manage AWS Directory Service and Amazon
>   EC2 resources, and attach the policy to the IAM users or groups that
>   require those permissions.

Typically, a root or power user credential is required to create new services such as Simple AD.

If you want to give specific users permission to create, manage, and destroy Simple AD directories and services, you can implement the policy below, and add that policy to any user/group desired.

```
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [
    {
      "Action" : [
        "ds:*",
        "iam:PassRole", 
        "iam:GetRole", 
        "iam:CreateRole", 
        "iam:PutRolePolicy", 
        "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
        "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
        "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
        "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
        "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
        "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
        "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
        "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
        "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
        "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
        "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress"
      ],
      "Effect" : "Allow",
      "Resource" : "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

This policy allows a user to login to the console, and gives them permission to manage **all** AWS Directory Service resources. The access to IAM resources is needed so that AWS Directory Service can read and create IAM roles on your behalf. Access to some Amazon EC2 resources is necessary to allow AWS Directory Service to create, configure, and destroy its directories.

Comment: Sorry I think I wasn't clear before. While this is also helpful, I need to setup an AD with IAM users in it. We don't have any directory system right now and don't want to create a AD with new user accounts, we want to import the existing IAM user accounts into simple AD. Is this possible? thanks!